# Using batch script I want to split a large file keeping the header same as master file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file. The first line is header. rest of the lines are data. It may contain thousand lines of data. I need to write a batch script which will split the master files into many files each of them contains maximum 500 lines of data and the same header as master file.

### Master file

```
heder
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
1501
```

it will split the file into 4 files. The fourth one will have the header and 1501

Answer (score 0):

You can get a total count of lines in a file using `find` and calculate the number of files needed by using a `for /l` loop on the count of the lines in steps of 500

the below approach examples such - in this way files are created with the header and lines output in accordance with the 500 per file using a paired `GTR` `LEQ` conditional test.

```bat
@Echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"

:# Primary environment has Delayed Expansion Disabled until after assignment of input
:# to retain '!' characters.
 Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

 Set "line[i]="
 Set "files="

:# Get a count of total lines and how many files to make per 500
 for /f %%a in ('type "infile.txt"^|find "" /v /c') do Set /A TTL=%%a-1
 For /l %%i in (0 500 %TTL%)Do Set /A files+=1

 Set /P "Header=" <"infile.txt"

:# Delayed expansion provides protection against poison characters
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:# Create or Overide each outfile using the assigned input from set /p
 For /l %%i in (1 1 %files%)Do  >"Outfile%%i.txt" Echo(!Header!

 Endlocal

:# Outer for /f loop skips header line; counts each line in.
:# Inner for /l loop iterates over group size with assigned offset 'Stop'
:# Dual GTR LEQ conditional test of Lne[i] used to output in desired group
 For /f "Skip=1 Delims=" %%G in (infile.txt)Do (
  Set /A "Line[i]+=1"
  Set "Line=%%G"
  Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  Set "file[i]=0"
  For /l %%i in (0 500 !TTL!)Do (
   Set /A "Stop=%%i+500"
   Set /A "file[i]+=1"
   If !Line[i]! GTR %%i If !Line[i]! LEQ !Stop! (
    Title File: !file[i]! / !files! Line: !Line[i]! / !TTL!
    >>"Outfile!file[i]!.txt" Echo(!Line!
   )
  )
  Endlocal
 )
```

Answer (score -3):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a maxNoOfLinesPerFile = 500
set /a lineCount = 0
set /a fileCount = 0
set header=""
set outFileNamePrefix=outFile

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (source.txt) do ( 
    
    if !lineCount!==0 (
        set header=%%A
    ) else (
        set /a n = !lineCount! %% !maxNoOfLinesPerFile!
        REM echo !n!
        if !n!==1 (
            set /a fileCount = fileCount + 1
            set outFileName=!outFileNamePrefix!_!fileCount!.txt
            echo !outFileName!
            echo !header! >> !outFileName!
            echo %%A >> !outFileName!
        ) else (
            echo %%A >> !outFileName!
        )
    )
        
    set /a lineCount = lineCount + 1    
)
```